# php mysql + ajax + jquery + delete action

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

i am creating a comment system using the php and mysql to store data and ajax with jquery  all the system work well but when it comes to the delete action nothing it happen like this button do not have any action or relation with the system can anyone help me ???

## comment_box.php

```
<li class="comment-holder" id="_<?php echo $comment->comment_id;  ?>">
    <div class="user-img">
     <img src="<?php echo $user->profile_img; ?>" class="user-img-pic" />
      </div>
      <div class="comment-body">
            <h3 class="username-field">
                     <?php echo $user->userName; ?>
             </h3>
              <div class="comment-text">
                   <?php echo $comment->comment; ?>         
              </div>
        </div>
         <div class="comment-buttons-holder">
            <ul>
                <li id="<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>"class="delete-btn">X</li>
             </ul>
          </div>
      </li>
```

## comment_delete.js(i am testing the delete button with firebug)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delete-btn').each(function() {
        var btn = this;
        $(btn).click(function(){
            console.log("the id " + btn.id);

        })      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delete-btn').each(function(i,el) {
        $(el).click(function(){
            console.log("the id " + $(this).attr('id'));

        })      
    });
});
```

Comment: still nothing appear in the console like this button do not have any action but it have an id so each button have its unique ID how to fix this

Comment: i tried your example but still nothing appear in the console what the hell is happen ??

Comment: Try close and reopen your browser - the Firebug and Webkit console can crash sometimes. For that reason I create a visual example (When you click you see the results on #display container

Comment: i did restart the browser but still nothing appear and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>"class="delete-btn">X</li>
```

Since you are missing whitespace here between the id value and the `class` attribute, I think the browser just does not assign that class to the element.

---

Edit (for people who don’t know what “missing” means):

Your PHP code will generate HTML output of the form

```
<li id="123"class="delete-btn">X</li>
```

whereas it should of course be

```
<li id="123" class="delete-btn">X</li>
```

---

Please *always* [*validate*](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML code *before* asking questions.

Comment: you mean in this line **<li id="<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>"class="delete-btn">X</li>**   but where is the white space???

Comment: still nothing change  i edit the line and ad withe space **<li id="<?php echo $comment->comment_id; ?>" class="delete-btn">X</li>**

Comment: When using jQuery, `this` is something different than `$(this)`. To access the element an event occurred on inside the handler, use the latter.

Comment: THe `whitespace` is not the problem - see this example  http://jsfiddle.net/AVBWB/1

Comment: And http://jsfiddle.net/AVBWB/2/ duplicate ids its not a valid HTML by WC3, but since jQuery click have closure $(this) will have a reference to comment id

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.delete-btn').click(function() {
        var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(comment_id);
    });
});
```